# default parameter set to empty dict acts as NoneType

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a function that updates 4 dictionaries by priority.
When testing, I found out that in some cases not all 4 will be provided.

The function fails of course because I am trying to use `update` on a `NoneType`.

```
@staticmethod
def create_configuration(layer1, layer2, layer3, layer4):
    configuration = {}
    configuration.update(layer4)
    configuration.update(layer3)
    configuration.update(layer2)
    configuration.update(layer1)
    return configuration
```

I tried to set the parameters, in the function signature, to be 
`layer3={}` and `layer3=dict()` but in both ways, when I run it, the dictionary will be a `NoneType`.

Is there a more elegant way to do it, rather than looping over the variables and setting them to an empty `dict` if they are `NoneType`?

Answer (score 1):

Many options.

The reason your default arguments do nothing is that you do in fact give an argument for those parameters, that happens to be None. So the default is unused.

One option, fix the code that calls this function. If this function expects four dicts and gets None instead of a dict, then something is wrong on that side.

But there is nothing special about needing four dicts in this code. It could instead be:

```
def combines_dicts(*dicts):
    combined = {}
    for d in dicts:
        combined.update(d)
    return combined
```

Now the calling code could give two, or five, arguments if it had that many dicts.

You could also fix it using `if`:

```
if layer4:
    configuration.update(layer4)
```

Et cetera.

Comment: It couldn't be without reversing: `for d in reversed(dicts):`